# could someone explain that C++ code for me?

Tags: c++, for-loop, for-range

In the following code what is the meaning of colon? and where callback function came from?

```cpp
using void_callback_f = void (*)();
std::vector<void_callback_f> _reload_callbacks;

void Reload() {
    for (const auto& callback : _reload_callbacks) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: If you meaning the colon in for loop it is kind of foreach loop without counting the index. It is one way to write for loop in c++, javascripts etc.

Comment: Ardahan Kisbet : thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ardahan Kisbet : what about callback function there is no declaration for it in the code?

Comment: also duplicates: [In for (int val :arr), what does the colon mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47275141/995714), [What does “ for (const auto &s : strs) {} ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22225148/995714), [What is “for (x : y)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24946027/995714)

Comment: phuclv : thank you for your comments I understand now the problem is the return type in my code was function which confused me a lot. thank you again for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon in the for loop is an example of **`Range-based for loop`**

> range_expression is evaluated to determine the sequence or range to
>   iterate. Each element of the sequence, in turn, is dereferenced and
>   assigned to the variable with the type and name given in
>   range_declaration.

Please check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for more information

Comment: what about callback function there is no declaration for it in the code? thank you for your answer.

Comment: Remy Lebeau : thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MuhammadRabieh yes, it is declared, by the `const auto& callback` in the loop. Did you even read the link Paul gave you? It explains how the syntax of the loop works. The [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) just means the type of `callback` is deduced by the compiler based on the type of container being looped through. Since a `std::vector<void_callback_f>` is being looped, the type of `callback` is deduced as `void_callback_f`. On each loop iteration, the next element of the vector gets assigned to `callback`

Comment: Remy Lebeau : thank you very much for your clarification.